# Kivy on Raspberry Pi: changing provider from EGL to SDL2?

Tags: python, kivy, raspberry-pi3

Running a Kivy application on my Raspberry Pi gives me an output like this:

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /home/pi/.kivy/logs/kivy_16-04-26_23.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.9.2-dev0
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v2.7.9 (default, Mar  8 2015, 00:52:26)
[GCC 4.9.2]
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 193 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_gif, img_pygame, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: pygame
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: egl_rpi
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <OpenGL ES 2.0>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <Broadcom>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <VideoCore IV HW>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 2, 0
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <OpenGL ES GLSL ES 1.00>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <2048>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <8>
[INFO   ] [Shader      ] fragment shader: <Compiled>
[INFO   ] [Shader      ] vertex shader: <Compiled>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[INFO   ] [OSC         ] using <multiprocessing> for socket
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
[INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
```

However, no window launches. Notice the `Provider: egl_rpi`.

In my Windows Kivy, the Provider is SDL2. Additionally, I am able to launch a sample mp3 video using SDL as the provider on the Raspberry Pi with:

```
sudo SDL_VIDEODRIVER=fbcon SDL_FBDEV=/dev/fb1 mplayer -vo sdl -framedrop test.mpg
```

My question is: how do I change the Provider to SDL2 for Kivy on the Pi?

Answer (score 2):

Adding the following line of code to the top of your Python file should switch the provider to sdl2

```
import os
os.environ['KIVY_WINDOW'] = 'sdl2'
```

Reference: [here](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/environment.html#restrict-core-to-specific-implementation)

I'm having the same issue as you, no window is displayed with `egl_rpi`. I switch to `SDL2` but the application fails to load. I believe this is due to a custom driver for my 3.5" SPI Display. Perhaps you'll have better luck with your video driver.